# button group in calendar

Tags: html, css, button, buttongroup

I am redesigning a very old piece of code which is a calendar ( please keep  in mind i want fix it just with html and css) the following snippet works well but the interface  breaks in Ipad so I changed the following code to the second snippet the interface is fine in ipad but it doesn't work .

```css
.dhx_cal_today_button{
 background-color: #e1e1e1;
 background-position:-30px 0;
  width:50px;
  height:17px;
  left:21px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:center;
  color: gray;
}

.dhx_cal_prev_button {
   background-position: 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 17px;
    left: 0px;
  width: 29px;
}


.dhx_cal_next_button {
   background-position: -60px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 17px;
    left: 75px;
  width: 29px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dhx_cal_prev_button buttonGroup">
  <button>&lt;</button>
</div>
<div class="dhx_cal_today_button buttonGroup">
<button >Today</button>
</div>
<div class="dhx_cal_next_button buttonGroup">
  <button >&gt;</button>
</div>
```

Second  code :

```css
.buttons {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
a.button {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
    -moz-transition: border .218s;
    -o-transition: border-color .218s;
    transition: border-color .218s;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
a.button:hover {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
a.button:active {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #444;
}
a.left {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a.middle {
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-left: solid 1px #f3f3f3;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
a.middle:hover,
a.right:hover { border-left: solid 1px #999 }
a.right {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-left: solid 1px #f3f3f3;
    border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

a.Today {

    width: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    margin:0;
  
}

a.prev {

    width: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
   
}
a.next {

    width: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="dhx_cal_prev_button button left prev">&lt;&nbsp;</a>
<a  href="#" class="dhx_cal_today_button button middle today">Today&nbsp;</a>
 <a  href="#" class="dhx_cal_next_button button right next">&gt;&nbsp;</a>
```

My understanding is when I use div it's work but the interface has problem and when i use  it's broken !!
( I can't use bootstrap , it was written in Php.)

```js
 EDIT: This is JS.
  // ----- Configure the dhtmlxScheduler options here -----
  
  this.scheduler.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"; // Format of dates loaded from server via json
  this.scheduler.config.date_step = "5";
  this.scheduler.config.first_hour = 7;
  //this.scheduler.config.last_hour = 24;  // {numeric} hour from which day and week scales start
  this.scheduler.config.hour_size_px = 50;
  this.scheduler.config.scroll_hour = 7;
  this.scheduler.config.multi_day = true;  // {numeric} hour from which day and week scales end.
  this.scheduler.config.readonly = false;
  this.scheduler.config.default_date = "%l %j %M %Y";
  
  this.scheduler.config.cascade_event_display = true; // to enable cascade rendering
  this.scheduler.config.cascade_event_count = 10; // how many levels (maximum) should be used
  this.scheduler.config.cascade_event_margin = 30; // margin in px between levels
 
  // Turn editing features off
  this.scheduler.config.drag_resize = false;  // - {boolean} allows resizing events by dnd;
  this.scheduler.config.drag_move = false;  // - {boolean} allows moving events by dnd;
  this.scheduler.config.drag_create = false;  // - {boolean} allows creating new events by dnd;
  this.scheduler.config.dblclick_create = false;  // - {boolean} allows creating new events by double click;
  this.scheduler.config.edit_on_create = false;  // - {boolean} shows form on new event creation;
  this.scheduler.config.details_on_create = false;  // - {boolean} uses extended form on new event creation by drag or by dbl-click (option doesn't affect monthly view - where details form is the only way to change data);
  this.scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick = false;
  //this.scheduler.xy.menu_width = 0;
  this.scheduler.config.full_day  = true;
  // this.scheduler.keys.edit_save = 13;

  if (this.allowTimeChange) {
   // Default is read only unless this.allowTimeChange is true
   this.scheduler.config.drag_resize = true;  // - {boolean} allows resizing events by dnd;
   this.scheduler.config.drag_move = true;  // - {boolean} allows moving events by dnd;
   this.scheduler.attachEvent("onClick", function(){return true;});
   this.scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeDrag", function(){return true;});
   this.scheduler.config.icons_edit=["icon_save"];
   this.scheduler.config.icons_select=["icon_save"];
  }
  else {
   // Disable clicks and drags
   this.scheduler.attachEvent("onClick",function(){return false;});
   this.scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeDrag",function(){return false;});
  }

  if (this.allowCreateEvents) {
   this.scheduler.config.drag_create = true;  // - {boolean} allows creating new events by dnd;
   this.scheduler.config.dblclick_create = true;  // - {boolean} allows creating new events by double click;
   this.scheduler.config.edit_on_create = true;  // - {boolean} shows form on new event creation;
  }

  this.scheduler.config.show_loading = true;

  this.overrideConfig();  /* allow final tweaking of config from calling screen */

  this.scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(), "month" /* is.weekMode */);
  
  this.scheduler.setLoadMode(this.loadMode);
  // this.scheduler.load(this.url, this.data_type);
  if (this.refreshOnInit) {
   this.refresh();
  }
  
 }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How it doesn't work?

Comment: when I press  next or previous or today , nothing happen , so it mean doesn't work.

Comment: You say *"the following snippet works well but the interface breaks in Ipad"* But non of both works.

Comment: yes the first one works well, but the interface has problem , it's break in ipad, if you run the first code , you will see

Comment: Here first one also not work.

Comment: Of course here none of them  works , because  it needs js codes. so  the problem is I ddin't change any code except html and css , but  in my code the first one is work and the second one doesn't , my understanding is some thing happen when i change the <div> to <a> , but I don't know what happen !!!!????

Comment: Show the JavaScript then. How can we say what's wrong when the snippets aren't complete?

Comment: I add the Javascript. Many thanks

Comment: *I can't use bootstrap , it was written in Php* I fail to see the connection

Comment: Don't be the glass half full or glass half empty person:) . reply the answer if you know mate!